# Sql Join Three table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

Here is my table ..and i want this output:

```
pid | pname | custname | quantity | total base price | sale price | profit
```

schema:

```
create table customers
(
    cid int,
    cname varchar(1000),
    cg varchar(1000)
)

create table prod
(
    pid int,
    pname varchar(1000),
    baseprice int,
    saleprice int
)

create table orders
(
    oid int,
    custid int,
    pid int,
    quantity int,
    odate date
)
```

How do I write a query for this?

Comment: look at [joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and are you using `mysql` or `sql-server`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--pid | pname | custname | quantity | total base price | sale price | profit
select o.pid, p.pname, c.cname AS custname, SUM(o.quantity) AS quantity, 
SUM(p.baseprice) AS 'total base price', SUM(p.saleprice) AS 'sale price', 
SUM(p.baseprice) - SUM(p.saleprice) AS profit -- change this math to what you need
from orders o join prod p
on o.pid = p.pid
join customers c
on o.custid = c.cid
group by o.pid, p.pname, c.cname
```

Comment: Actually ..it's working but i am not understood after  from orders o join prod p
on o.pid = p.pid
join customers c
on o.custid = c.cid
group by o.pid, p.pname, c.cname    can u please explain me what u did here

Comment: Any answer please.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are asking, but the query is using letters (o,p,c) to alias the tables so you don't have to use the full table name in the join later. And, the `group by` clause is necessary in order to `SUM` the values in the `select` clause. There, you group by the field(s) that you want to roll up values to. If this is a new concept, don't be too concerned, grouping is one of those things that can take a minute to grasp.

Comment: Please, do not demand a comment, or an answer. I do this for fun, not as a job.

Comment: thanks problem solved

Comment: Glad to help! Have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    a.pid , 
    a.pname , 
    c.cname , 
    b.quantity  , 
    a.baseprice * b.quantity as TotalBasePrice , 
    a.saleprice*b.quantity as TotalSalePrice ,
    a.saleprice*b.quantity - a.baseprice * b.quantity as profit   
from prod as a 
    inner join orders as b on a.pid = b.pid 
    inner join customers as c on b.custid = c.cid
```

Comment: Thanks Man u r gr8..it's working